# Is there any image application that can crop images that is faster/lighter than GIMP?

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation, screenshot, image-processing

From a screenshot I want to cut only the part that is important. I do know I can do it using GIMP, but GIMP is very slow to start. Is there any image application that can do it faster?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To crop images with **Shotwell** (the default picture viewer) just open the image and choose *Crop* from the *Photo -> Tools* menu. This will give you a highlighted frame you can drag with your mouse.

[image: cropping dialog]

Comment: Pinta also supports it

Comment: Right on the money! I was just about to instal GIMP solely for the reason of cropping images.. you saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 6):

You can use **Shotwell** which comes installed by default. just right click an image and select Open With from the context meny and then select Shotwell. Shotwell comes with a CROP feature so you can select which part of the image you want.

Answer (score 2):

If its something you want to do more than once (say from multiple screenshots) then its best to Alt-Print Screen to perform the image cuts and then use Imagemagick convert as follows:

```
convert -crop 400x300+50+200 screenshot.png test.png
```

will generate a 400x300 image as a subset of the original screenshot.png offset by 50 pixels east and 200 pixels south.

Its slow to sort the first time, but once you have done it once the other images can be put into a batch using a bash script.